# Supporting MOGA game controllers on Android TV

Tags: android, libgdx, television, gamecontroller

I would like to upgrade one of our MOGA-compatible games to support Android TV.

- Is MOGA game controllers supported by Android TV?
- Is MOGA still around? Their Facebook page is not updated since last year, and go to their developer site, click on the "Contact Us" - result in a page "The requested resource / is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource."

Thanks for any updates.